# How to reference a file with a generic portion in the filename using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a datalogger that generates a file every 24hrs.  The filename follows this format:
24hr_Export_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MinMin_SS.csv
The problem is with the hour, min, sec portion of the filename.  The "seconds(SS)" field is always different, due to the time it takes for the export to sync to my ftp, but I only need to verifiy the year, month, day portion of the filename to know what to import to my spreadsheet.  Is there a special character I can substitute for the final portion of the filename?
The code is below:

```
Path = "\\blah\blah\blah\"
Prefix = "24hr_Export_"
Suffix = "_00_00_14"
FName = Prefix & DayTime & Suffix & ".csv"
ImportCsvFile Path & FName, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

Sub ImportCsvFile(FileName As Variant, Position As Range)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FileName, Destination:=Position)
  .Name = Replace(FileName, ".csv", "")
  .FieldNames = True
  .RowNumbers = False
  .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
  .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
  .BackgroundQuery = True
  .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
  .SavePassword = False
  .SaveData = True
  .AdjustColumnWidth = True
  .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
  .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
  .TextFileStartRow = 1
  .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
  .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
  .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
  .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
  .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
  .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
  .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
  .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ","
  .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

where DayTime is formatted as mentioned above earlier in the macro, and the "14" in the suffix is arbitrary.

Comment: Once you've created the filename, do you do a `Workbooks.Open`?

Comment: The filename is generated when the datalogger exports it to a specific location.  I will schedule a task to open a particular workbook, run the macro, save and close the workbook on a daily basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search for the filename with `Dir` and use wildcards.

Let's say the file is named `24hr_Export_2013_11_15_16_22_00.csv` *(15 Nov 2013, 16:22:00)*.

Then you can either use the `*` wildcard to match multiple characters:

```
FName = Dir("c:\24hr_Export_2013_11_15_*.csv")
```

...or multiple `?` wildcards (each one matches a single character):

```
FName = Dir("c:\24hr_Export_2013_11_15_??_??_??.csv")
```

Both would find a file named *(for example)* `c:\24hr_Export_2013_11_15_16_22_00.csv`.

Comment: I was certain the asterisk could be used as a "wildcard" but I obviously didn't have the syntax.  Thank you Christian.